# php session timeout

Tags: php, session, timeout

I have some issues concerning the timeout of a php session. I have set the following values during runtime of the application:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
session.cookie_lifetime = 3600
session.save_path = myApplicationPath/tmp
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
```

However, my session keeps expiring in about 30 mins. Also, my tmp directory remains empty, so it appears no cookies are actually being set. echoing ini_get("session.save_path") does return the right path though.

Comment: Just to check: Ensure you're setting the ini values before you're calling `session_start`. Additionally compare with the output of `phpinfo()` you can place into a test-file.

Comment: values are indeed set before session_start. phpinfo states: local value var/www/myproject/tmp master value /etc/lib/php5. The session files are still written to the master value.

Comment: Found it! Using Zend_Session you don't get notices about a session started elsewhere. When I stopped using Zend_Session I got the notice. Putting my code way up in the bootstrap solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**

If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

Comment: The OP has rather described the opposite behavior: The sessions do not  expire until 30 minutes although *session.gc\_maxlifetime* states 6 minutes.

Comment: AFAIU `session.gc_maxlifetime` is 1 hour and sessions die before they should do

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, it’s my fault. Don’t know how I ever could misinterpret 3600 seconds as 6 instead of 60 minutes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that PHP cannot find your `save_path` or does not have permission to write on that, so it stores session files (*not* cookies) in the default shared directory (so the site with shortest `gc_maxlifetime` will remove sessions from all other sites).

Comment: That would be my own guess as well. Output of save_path gives me the correct path however, and the directory has 777 permissions.

Comment: session files are indeed written to the default dir. What am I missing here?

Comment: `session.save_path = myApplicationPath/tmp`: Does your real path actually not start with slash?